# until command in Bash

Tags: bash

How does the until command work in bash? For the following code,

`i=10;
until [ $i -lt 1 ]; do
    let i--
    echo $i
done`

I would think that once it gets to `until [ 1 -lt 1 ]`, it would fail and hence print the digits 9 to 1. But it prints 9 to 0. Am I missing something? When was `1 < 1` proven to be true?

Comment: echo $((--i))    combines  decrementing, then echoing i, in one operation.  (( i < 1 ))  for comparing may be way more readable,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly just to cover the bases:

The **while** executes a piece of code if the control expression is true, and only stops when it is false (or a explicit break is found within the executed code.

The **until** loop is almost equal to the while loop, except that the code is executed while the control expression evaluates to false as they are equal at that point.

Ultimately though your question is answered with:

There is actually an explicit operator for *less than or equal to*.

**-lt**
is less than

```
if [ "$a" -lt "$b" ]
```

**-le**
is less than or equal to

```
if [ "$a" -le "$b" ]
```

The `until [ 1 -lt 1 ]` statement when read out loud would go, "Until 1 is l less than 1".

When 1 = 1 on the "last" iteration `$i` would be reduced to zero within the loop and be printed as the next iteration of the loop will break out.

**Example**

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 COUNTER=20
 echo COUNTER OUTSIDE LOOP $COUNTER
 until [  $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
     echo COUNTER $COUNTER
     let COUNTER-=1
 done
```

Answer (score 1):

To add, the more efficient way to do it (in terms of coding space) is to use a `for` loop:

```
for (( i = 9; i >= 0; --i )); do
    echo "$i"
done
```

And it's also a good practice to initialize your counter from the first number that you'd actually use, and not the number that would be deducted or incremented to gain the first. Not unless you're after efficiency over readability that may be questioned.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "initialize your counter from the first number that you'd actually use"?

Comment: He needed to print 9 first but in his loop he started with 10.